# How to wait a function for a variable change without locking the main thread without additional threads, and loops

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I need the solution for the following scenario:

I have a DeviceCenter class that listens 3 additional devices that are controlled by the class Device.
This Device objects named DeviceA, DeviceB and DeviceC are getting asynchronous data from their real-life hardware from some sensors.

I need to solve below snippet without using while loops, additional threads to prevent the main-thread that runs the below function.

There is a condition like this: When DeviceA gets the data temperatureOverflow, DeviceCenter must call a function named OnTemperatureOverflow. In this OnTempratureOverflow function there is a snippet like this.

```
void DeviceCenter::OnTemperatureOverflow()
{
// some processes.
while(sharedData.TemperatureLed == LedOn)
{
  // do nothing and wait.
}
QWriteLocker writeLocker(&sharedData.readWriteLock);
sharedData.SomeLed = LedOn;
// some processes.
}
```

I have thought of creating a function-tree (a binary tree) that will track the function to see where it is left and when the shared data is updated it would be checking the function's current state and continue from there but i can't handle the logic itself.

I would appreciate to hear other methods to achieve this or it is even possible.
Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: In the GUI thread `while(sharedData.TemperatureLed == LedOn) {}` is probably not desired in the first place. Remember that the GUI only updates and responds when your functions exit.

Comment: Is `DeviceCenter::OnTemperatureOverflow` a slot? If it is, what prevents you from having another slot to react to a signal that is triggered when `sharedData.TemperatureLed` is changed to `LedOn`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to this:

```
void DeviceCenter::OnTemperatureOverflow()
{
   // some processes.
   if (sharedData.TemperatureLed == LedOn) {
      QWriteLocker writeLocker(&sharedData.readWriteLock);
      sharedData.SomeLed = LedOn;
      // some processes.
   }
}
```

If `OnTemperatureOverflow` is a slot, connect it to appropriate signal. if not, define it as slot then use connection from the signal.

If there are some processes before and after that aren't related to the slot function, you should separate those and move them to a new function.